# Move only on verify?

Tags: mv, file-transfer

For some reason, copying files from my phone over the MTP fuse interface sometimes results in corrupt files, missing their last few bytes. I want to remove each file on successful transfer, but *not* remove them if there was a problem. The `mv` command doesn't have a `--verify` option. I could write a short script which copies, checks, and removes, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant existing command which can handle this?

As a bonus, it'd be nice to specify both checksum match and success from an external verification command, in this case `jpeginfo -c`. I *think* the short reads are random occurrences, but I haven't really tested that the bad file isn't actually cached that way (or otherwise would be read incorrectly in the same way twice). So, something like `mv --verify --verifywith='jpeginfo -c'` would be ideal (where `jpeginfo -c` is a command that tests JPEG files for correctness and which I know will return an error on these particular truncated files).

Answer (score 3):

rsync can do this with `--remove-source-files`. From `man rsync` (emphasis mine):

> This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and *have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side*.

I'm not sure how it verifies successful duplication, other than that it will not remove them if an error occurred during the process. It's quite possible that that is all it does.

If the interface is silently corrupting files, however, I think even copy/check/remove will not really fix your problem, since even the check might produce false results.

Since you mention MTP and a phone, I'm going to guess you're using Android. If you'd consider an alternative FUSE interface, you might like to try [adbfs](http://collectskin.com/adbfs/).